# Thousands separator in jQuery is causing parseFloat to misinterpret numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsefloat

I am using a `.` as a thousands separator.
So the string `128.814` should be read as "one hundred and twenty eight thousand, eight hundred and fourteen".

When I add this to the number 900, I want the answer to be 129714 (displayed as `129.714`).
However, because javascript takes the thousands separator as a decimal point, it's giving me an undesirable result.

```
function addTotalPrice(item){
    var priceItem = parseFloat( $(item).find('.price').text() );
    var priceTotal = parseFloat( $('.label-price span').text() );

    var result = (priceTotal + priceItem);
    $('.label-price span').text( result.toFixed(3) );
}
```

How can I tell jQuery/Javascript to interpret the `.` in `128.814` as a thousands separator and not a decimal point?

Comment: Can you PLEASE tell us what the problem is exactly? Its working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/ac0vnjos/

Comment: Agreed, also did a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6ajs9zkx/ and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I need this result 129.714

Comment: Huh? Sorry, but maths is maths. You cannot dispute that `900 + 128.814 === 1028.814`

Comment: @bgs264, no, I think he means 128.814 is actually 128,814

Comment: @GrigoreanAlexander, what should we do with the `.`? In American standard mathematics, `.` represents a fraction and not a comma to indicate hundered thousand

Comment: Can we just remove any `.`s?

Comment: @GrigoreanAlexander, see my most recent answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell jQuery/Javascript to interpret the . in 128.814 as a
>   thousands separator and not a decimal point?

Simplest way would be to remove it.

When you remove it, it will **automatically** be interpreted as a thousands value, even without the comma there. Then, manually format the number like in [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

```
function addTotalPrice(item){
    var priceItem = parseFloat( $(item).find('.price').text().replace('.','') );
    var priceTotal = parseFloat( $('.label-price span').text().replace('.','') );

    var result = (priceTotal + priceItem);
    $('.label-price span').text( result.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."); );
}
```

```js
var priceItem = parseFloat('900'.replace('.', ''));
var priceTotal = parseFloat('128.814'.replace('.', ''));

var result = (priceTotal + priceItem);
var fixedResult = result.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
document.write(fixedResult);
```

Comment: I am sorry for my not correct question. Your answer works fine, thank you